# performing a task when all futures are completed in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have to execute about 10 to 15 queries concurrently. Where, those queries are dependent on each other, I have put those queries together in one future. Otherwise, I have one future per query. Now I simply want when all my queries are executed then a response indicating success or failure from the functions containing the future.

```
val f1 = future{SQL("insert into user_general_info (user_id, userFName, userLName, displayAs)" +
  "values(" + userId + ",'" + form.fname + "','" + form.lname + "','1')").executeInsert();
}

val f2 = future {
  SQL("insert into personal('" + userId + "',1,1,0,0,1,'ALL',0,'E')").executeInsert();
}

/*
and so on...upto about f1 to f14 futures...
*/
```

now what i did is:

```
val job = for {
  a1 <- f1
  a2 <- f2
  a3 <- f3
  a4 <- f4
  a5 <- f5
  a6 <- f6
  a7 <- f7
  a8 <- f8
  a9 <- f9
  a10 <- f10
  a11 <- f11
  a12 <- f12
  a13 <- f13
  a14 <- f14
} yield ()

var res: Boolean = false

job.onSuccess {
  case result => res = true
}

if(res)
  List((1, userId, username)) //1 means success
else
  List((-2, userId, username)) //-2 means failure
```

The problem is that all queries didn't run and the response `List((-2,userId,username))` is sent based on variable res. But the `List((1,userId,username))` should have been returned when all the futures are completed. Help...

Comment: Another problem with the method you show is that the queries are not performed concurrently, but instead sequentially. The for comprehension for futures provides a means to chain futures into a sequence so that those later in the sequence are only executed if those before succeed. tehlexx's answer is correct and is what you are looking for in this case (i.e. use Future.sequence and not a for comprehension).

Comment: @MarkS Are you sure about that. If he defines the futures before the for comprehension then all futures are executed immediately in a concurrently manner. The for comprehension only waits for the results. So if the first future needs the most time than the first flatMap gets executed if this result is completed. And then all other flatMap chains are executed immediately, because all other futures are already completed. I may be wrong.

Comment: @akkie You're right, if the future has already been created. I was stuck imagining that the future is created within the for comprehension. Of course, if they are created prior to, then they will be executed regardless (and in parallel).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Futures.sequence` to transform a list of futures in a single future.

Code example from [Composing Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html#Composing_Futures):

```
// oddActor returns odd numbers sequentially from 1 as a List[Future[Int]]
val listOfFutures = List.fill(100)(akka.pattern.ask(oddActor, GetNext).mapTo[Int])

// now we have a Future[List[Int]]
val futureList = Future.sequence(listOfFutures)

// Find the sum of the odd numbers
val oddSum = futureList.map(_.sum)
oddSum foreach println
```

On a side note, I would suggest returning an `Option` to indicate success or failure, for example

```
if(res) Some(List(userId, userName))
else None
```